# Swift delegate variable always nil when function is called

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've created the following delegate, and no matter what I try, selectedTransaction comes back as nil when the `reconcile()` function is called. I'm going through the delegate pattern as I have different modes and data requirements, etc.

```swift
class MatchReconciliationViewState: ReconciliationDelegate {
    var selectedTransaction: Transaction?
    let statementLine: StatementLine
    
    init(selectedTransaction: Transaction? = nil, statementLine: StatementLine) {
        self.selectedTransaction = selectedTransaction
        self.statementLine = statementLine
    }
    
    func canReconcile() -> Bool {
        return nil != selectedTransaction
    }
    
    func reconcile() {
        print("reconcile: \(String(describing: selectedTransaction))")
        guard let selectedTransaction = selectedTransaction else { return }
        
        ReconciliationFunctions.match(statementLine: statementLine, toTransaction: selectedTransaction)
    }
}
```

The child view is a simple list that selects the an object in the list (this part works).
These value prints in the onChange show that I'm actually holding data (onChange occurs in a child view):

```swift
.onChange(of: selectedTransaction) { newValue in
    print("onChange: \(String(describing: selectedTransaction))")
    reconciliationDelegate.selectedTransaction = newValue
    parentState.canReconcile = reconciliationDelegate.canReconcile()
    print("onChangeDelegate: \(String(describing: reconciliationDelegate.selectedTransaction))")
}
```

But when I come to use it, the value of selectedTransaction is always nil (triggered from a button on parent view):

```swift
private func reconcileStatementLine() {
    print("delegate: \(String(describing: state.reconciliationDeleage))")
    state.reconciliationDeleage?.reconcile()
//        persistence.commit()
//        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
}
```

The protocl:

```swift
public protocol ReconciliationDelegate: AnyObject {
    func canReconcile() -> Bool
    func reconcile()
}
```

view:

```swift
@StateObject var state: ReconciliationViewState

var body: some View {
    Button(action: reconcileStatementLine) {
        Text("Reconcile")
    }
}

private func reconcileStatementLine() {
    print("delegate: \(String(describing: state.reconciliationDeleage))")
    state.reconciliationDeleage?.reconcile()
//        persistence.commit()
//        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
}
```

ReconciliationViewState holds the value as such (there are @Published properties, but are not pertinent to the question):

```swift
class ReconciliationViewState: ObservableObject {
    var reconciliationDeleage: ReconciliationDelegate? = nil
}
```

What am I missing or not understanding?

Comment: How are you storing the delegate? Can you show a [mre]?

Comment: I tried the following `var reconciliationDeleage: ReconciliationDelegate? = nil` i used to have it with `weak` too. It's held in the parent's view ObservableObject. When I press the button, the print statement in my question does show the delegate object and I know the function is called as I get the print from within it.

Comment: Each child view has it's own implementation that conforms to the delegate protocol

Comment: Without an MRE, it's too vague to guess concretely about what's going on.

Comment: Please don't use protocol/delegate in Swift(UI) at all. It's old *objective-c-ish* stuff.

Comment: @vadian how would you suggest I deal with multiple subviews that have different data requirements, but that perform the same action of reconciliation?

Comment: @jnpdx, I've updated the snippets for what was explained in text. I'm just trying to understand why a referenced object's inner variable magically becomes nil when the `reconcile()` function gets called from the parent view who took a reference to the object. Despite me confirming with a `print()` that i did assign a value into the variable.
Just to confirm, the delegate itself wasn't disposed, I've confirmed that the specific function does get called.

Comment: What you've shared isn't a [mre] (`state` never gets set, it's unclear where `reconcileStatementLine`, etc), so it's not possible to debug.

Comment: `state` gets initialized when the view itself gets created (out of scope of the question, I'm not gonna upload a full project here...). `reconcileStatementLine` was explained in text form, but I've added duplicated it in it's context of use. 
I posted here to hopefully get the help from someone who would've used this design pattern and could understand why an object value that is set (confirmed through debugging...) is processed as nil when the function, of that same object is called, yet the object itself is still allocated. I purposely also commented out the view dismissal to keep in memory

Comment: You call a function on `reconciliation`, but that doesn’t exist. Is it supposed to be on `state`?

Comment: @jndpx, I've found the answer with a bit of AI help, although I cannot explain why it fixes the issue. I might be missing some understanding on how swift manages references. Although I had removed any instances that could cause memory deallocation (ex: dismissing the view) to debug.

Comment: for `You call a function on reconciliation, but that doesn’t exist. Is it supposed to be on state?` That was a typo in renaming for readability here, was trying to remove domain specific lingo and replace it with a concept. If this was in the codebase, compiler would've picked it up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't quite get why swift / swift UI works this way or why this fixed the issue, but this is what I arrived at with the help of chatGPT.

The way of declaring the variable seems to be what does the trick:

```swift
//    var reconciliationDelegate: MatchReconciliationViewState
    var reconciliationDelegate: MatchReconciliationViewState {
            get { parentState.ReconciliationDelegate as! MatchReconciliationViewState }
        }
    
// [...]

.onAppear() {
            let delegate = MatchReconciliationViewState(statementLine: parentState.statementLine)
            parentState.ReconciliationDelegate = delegate
}
// instead of during init due to how the variable is now declared.
```

the old init code:

```swift
var reconciliationDelegate: MatchReconciliationViewState

init(/*[...]*/) {
// [...]
reconciliationDelegate = MatchReconciliationViewState(statementLine: parentState.statementLine)
parentState.ReconciliationDelegate = reconciliationDelegate
// [...]
```

Very weird behaviour as I did have my reference to the instance, the right implementation of the function was being executed, but the delegate's property `selectedTransaction` would come back to nil during the delegate's function execution.